# Can I pretend that a cross-domain AJAX response will be JSONP if I don't care about the result?

Tags: ajax, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I'm making a GET request to a network camera that tells the camera to move in a certain way, e.g. pan, tilt, zoom, etc. I don't need a response from the camera's built-in web server, which is obviously a different host than the one where the calling JavaScript code resides. I was trying to make a jQuery `$.ajax` request, which was not allowed due to the same origin policy. But when I change the `'dataType'` setting to `'jsonp'` it seems to work just fine in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. Besides being a bit kludgy, are there any technical problems with this approach that will ever prevent it from sending the messages to the camera?

Comment: You can *fire* any kind of GET request, only you won't be allowed to access the results. Whether the request is made with XHR, a script tag, an image element or an iframe does not matter. However, if you are using a jsonp-like script tag, the result will get executed - which might do harm to your page, or throw syntax errors.

Comment: Make a server side webmethod, that hits your local server and relays that on the webcam server, handle the response on the server and return back to client.

Comment: @cgatian: He said he does not need the response at the client.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I thought about using an image element but I didn't want a broken image to appear in IE. Perhaps an iframe would be a cleaner way to do it. The result is empty so while it does fire the error callback it does not seem to cause any errors that would kill the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your camera is just expecting a `GET` request at that specific URL, then no, it won't make a difference. A JSONP request is essentially adding a pair of script tags to your document:

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

The `callback` parameter is added to the URL so that when the resulting script is loaded, it executes a global callback function. jQuery hides this pretty well with `$.ajax`, so you don't notice it.

Comment: It does fire the error callback, but doesn't throw any unhandled errors, so I guess I'll stop worrying about it.